# No Results by Content Search Webpart

Tags: content-search-web-part

Why I get no results in my Content search Webpart in Office 365? The query Shows me results by testing, but not in the site.

Comment: Seeing your query would help solving the issue

Answer (score 3):

What license do you have?

If you do not meet the license requirements which is any of the Office 365 **Enterprise** plans, you will see the webpart, be able to add it to a page and create a query and get results while testing it in the dialog, but it simply won't work in the site.

> Q: Which SharePoint Online plans include the search-driven publishing
>   features?
>
> A: The Content Search Web Part and Cross-site Publishing are available
>   for Office 365 for Enterprise plans. Specifically, these plans are: 
>   Office 365 Enterprise E3 and E4, Office 365 Education A3 and A4,
>   Office 365 government G3 and G4, and Office 365 Enterprise E3 for
>   Nonprofits.

[Search innovations for site and portal design in SharePoint Online](https://blogs.office.com/2013/10/29/search-innovations-for-site-and-portal-design-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Ok I have the Plan E1. But why it's possible to add and configure the content search webpart in my Plan?

Comment: I asked myself the same question a couple of days ago. It's there to tease/show what you can have if you upgrade your license.